# WebServiceHost: Blocking call in a webservice method blocks whole service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF webservice using the WebServiceHost class.

new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceClass));

If I use a blocking call like Thread.Sleep (just an example) in one of my webservice methods and i call this method the whole service is not usable while the blocking call is active.

Is that normal behaviour or is there an error somewhere in my configuration or usage?

Comment: You categorically should *not* be making calls to Thread.Sleep in your web service.   But theburningmonk's answer is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. If you start the service in a windows forms GUI thread you can add

```
UseSynchronizationContext = false
```

to the ServiceBehavior and the requests get handled in parallel. :)

Answer (score 2):

What's the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) and [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) settings on your service? If it's set to Single then there's only one instance of your service and all the calls are queued so if you put the service thread to sleep it will block all subsequent calls.

For example:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
}
```